# Moving data from SQL Server to Oracle using T-SQL Jobs and Linked Server

Tags: sql-server, oracle, jobs, database-replication, linked-server

I have a SQL Server database in a Windows2012R2 Server and a Oracle database in a Linux environement.

My goal is to send, every x minutes, specific data from specific tables from my SQL Server database to my Oracle database.

I was thinking about using "instead of triggers" to automaticly send data to Oracle through Linked Server but I have been asked to choose an alternative because this solution involves an use of a gateway, due to DTC issues between Windows and Linux, which is not affordable for the company I am working for.

My alternative is to use triggers to copy the specific data of my SQL Server database into new tables of that database and then use a SQL Job to fetch data and send it to the Oracle database through a Linked Server. I have been thinking about using two Jobs to fetch and send that data but I dont know how to implement it, i would like it to act as load balancing. Moreover I have to check process on both ends.

I know I could use materialized views and sort of stream replication but this solution is more complex and I dont have time enough for.

So I have been wondering if my solution is the more suitable for the task I have to do and what would be the best approaches?

(i am sorry if I am not that accurate in my way to talk, I am a novice in that field)

Comment: How many tables are you updating, and what's the velocity of CRUD edits on those tables? You don't need to be precise, but having a general idea would be good.

Comment: I have to update and fetch data from about 5 tables  and insert update/delete/inserted rows into a single table in my Oracle databas. I may have hundreds rows to handle. I dont think that velocity will be an issue as we have clusters.

Comment: And when you say, "specific data" do you mean any data that has changed, or have you got a predefined query that will extract that data for you? Are you able to run that query and send over the full dataset, or do you have to remove deltas? It might come down to volume of records, and the likely file sizes, but it sounds relatively low-volume. In terms of inter-system connectivity, can you generate and send files over (s)ftp? Or some shared network location? Do you have an inter-system messaging bus, or queuing system you could hook into?

Comment: The goal is to create notifications after an update/delete/insert on specific data. So I have to detect changes and copy the data in its old version in a 'notification_temp' table in the same sql server database using three different triggers. Then I have to use a Job to extract that table in another table 'notification', in my Oracle database, and sending the content there via a Linked Server. After I am running a script to check if that notification table has content and if that's the case, I compare old data and current data in order to generate the notification message.

Comment: Once the notification message generated, i store it in another table and use its content to send notifications to users. I could generate and send files but i am not that attracted by that solution. I dont have any messaging bus or queuing system yet. And thanks a lot for helping!

Comment: I might be tempted to create a mirror of your notification table in the source database, that way, you can populate it cleanly without worrying about connectivity - then, by keeping a record of notifications, you can extract pages, and send a neatly formatted file between servers in discrete chunks for direct upload into your target. That way, you keep most of the tricky code in one place, and don't have to worry about maintaining two systems in tandem.

Comment: Sorry, I missed your preference for not sending files as communication between servers - which is fair enough - one advantage is that it's all quite pedestrian and simple to do, and each file acts as a kind of log to prove that transmission has taken place. If you rule out files, messaging/queues etc, then the only remaining alternative is a cross-platform database-link. Which is fine, but potentially makes life harder in the long-run should either Microsoft, or Oracle upgrade in a direction that no longer supports the continuation of the link.

Comment: Thanks a lot @TomKimber but why would it make life harder?Another question for you: do you know what would be the best approach to use parallel Jobs to send that data through a linked server ?

Comment: It's a personal preference thing, but database linkages can sometimes make upgrades, migrations, backups and restores more difficult to achieve cleanly. A good general practice to follow is [loose coupling](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Loose_coupling) which anticipates future changes and limits the impacts of those changes.

Comment: Thanks a lot @TomKimber this is helping me !